# Is this proof of Schröder-Bernstein Theorem correct?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, logic

If we know of the law of trichotomy, can we prove Schröder-Bernstein Theorem just by saying that if A $\preceq$B and B$\succeq$A, then it isn't be possible that A $\prec$B and it isn't possible that $A \succ B$, so we can conclude that $A \sim B$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well yes, but usually trichotomy is presented as a consequence of Schröder-Bernstein.So you just moved the problem to proving trichotomy.